# Probability that six couples attending a marriage seminar are divided into six groups of two people of the same gender

Tags: probability

A total of twelve attendees consisting of six couples are attending a marriage seminar. An activity during the seminar had to randomly group the attendees into six groups of two attendees. What is the probability that each group contains attendees of the same gender only？

I think it may be 
$$\frac{6}{12} \cdot \frac{5}{11} \cdot \frac{4}{10} \cdot \frac{3}{9} \cdot \frac{2}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{7}$$

I first think about the total possible group that can be formed. There are $$\frac{(12C2)(10C2)(8C2)(6C2)(4C2)(2C2)}{6！}$$

Comment: I am so weak on probability problem. I think it may be 6/12*5/11*4/10*3/9*2/8*1/7

Comment: $\frac{2}{\binom{12}{6}}$ or alternatively $\frac{2!\cdot6!\cdot6!}{12!}$ (in either case, the answer is $\frac{1}{462}$).

Comment: Why the ans is that？ could u please explain to me ？

Comment: Could you first explain what you've tried (as part of your question please)?

Comment: I first think about the total possible group that can be formed. There are (12C2)(10C2)(8C2)(6C2)(4C2)(2C2) / 6！

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to let the seniormost person left have the choice of partner at each stage, thus:

- Women only: eldest has $5$ choices, then eldest left has $3$ choices, etc: $5\cdot 3\cdot 1 = 15$ ways
- Men only: Similarly, $15$ ways
- No constraints: $11\cdot9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot 1 = 10395$ ways
- Pr$= \dfrac{15\cdot15}{10395} = \dfrac5{231}$

**ADDED**

- although the word "choice" has been used, it is to be understood that the "choices" are random, by giving secret numbers $1-12$ to them, say.
- the result can be neatly encapsulated as $Pr =\dfrac{(5!!)^2 }{(11!!)}$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the number of ways of forming six groups of two people is 
$$\frac{1}{6!} \cdot \binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
By the same reasoning, the number of ways of forming three groups of two women is 
$$\frac{1}{3!} \cdot \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$
which is also the number of ways of forming three groups of two men.  Hence, the probability that the six couples attending the marriage seminar are divided into six groups of two people of the same gender is 
$$\frac{\left[\dfrac{1}{3!} \cdot \dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{2}{2}\right]^2}{\dfrac{1}{6!} \cdot \dbinom{12}{2}\dbinom{10}{2}\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{2}{2}}$$